# how to add repeating strings value in json array

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON as

var newJSON = [{"key":"India","value":"72"},{"key":"India","value":"27"},{"key":"Pakistan","value":"90"},{"key":"Zimbamwe","value":"88"},{"key":"India","value":"100"},{"key":"Pakistan","value":"172"}]

I want desired result as

[{"key":"India","value":"199"},{"key":"Pakistan","value":"262"},{"key":"Zimbamwe","value":"88"}]

Please help me with this

Comment: `{ "India", 200 }` is not valid syntax and there is no such kind of object in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure you want them as `{"india","20"}`??

or is it `{"india":"20"} //this is recommended`

then you can do 
`json["india"]`
or `json[0]`

**Update:**

```
var yourObj={key:'india', value:72};
var newObj = {};
newObj[yourObj.key] = yourObj.value;
newObj["Austria"]=100; // adds as a new list object
```

Comment: I want to convert Object {key: "India", value: "72"} to Object {India : "72"} please help me with that

Answer (score 0):

You could use

var jsondata =[];

```
        var firstvalue = {country:"India",number:"200"};
        jsondata.push(firstvalue);

        var secondvalue = {country:"Australia",number: "210"};
        jsondata.push(secondvalue);
        for(var i =0; i< jsondata.length;i++){
            console.log(jsondata[i].country);
        }
```